# Items from an external Json-File in a Selectbox. How to change order?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my selectbox, I load an external json-File with a lot of currencies.

**Json-Example**

```
{
    "EUR": {
        "symbol": "€",
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol_native": "€",
        "decimal_digits": 2,
        "rounding": 0,
        "code": "EUR",
        "name_plural": "euros"
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownCurrency">
            <li ng-repeat="currency in data.locations.currencies">
                <a>{{ currency.code}} {{currency.name}} </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
function CtrlInvoice($scope, $http) {


    $scope.data = {
        "locations": {}
    };


    $http.get('l10n/currencies.json')
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.data.locations.currencies = res.data;
        $scope.$apply();
      });
}
```

Actually, All Json-Items are sorted alphabetically by "code":

1. In the file, I have compiled the most important currencies to the beginning. But the selectbox is still sorted by "code". Is there any chance to change this to my defined order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried orderBy on ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: Yes I´ve already tried orderBy: ng-repeat="currency in data.locations.currencies | orderBy:code" The items in my selectbox are still sorted alphabetically and my order in the json-file will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

O.k., I found the problem:

I have to delete the Group "EUR": , "USD": etc. and then it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to make the items an array instead of an object.